# DOMsubtreemodified equivalent in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom

Does anyone know the equivalent of this event in IE ?

Or may be a way around for this logic:

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function (e) {
            if ($(e.target).hasClass("myclass")) {
                var getId= e.target.id;
            }
        }, false)
```

This works fine in FF, Chrome, Safari, IE 9 or higher.

Need an equivalent logic for IE8 and IE7

Comment: A short answer: an equivalent event doesn't exist in IE<9. However, changes to some elements/properties fire [`onpropertychange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event.

Comment: you can always ping and trigger a custom event upon a change detection... getElemementsByTagName("*") will change it's .length property when elements are added or removed.

Comment: I'd suggest writing your code in such a way that you don't depend on these kinds of events.

Comment: @dandavis That's what my 2nd option was.

Comment: @KevinB : I am implementing other option now, which won't need this event :(

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem (though I was using jQuery).  I solved it by using the following

```
//chrome / ff
$(".myClass").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
//do stuff
});     

//i.e.
$(".myClass").on("propertychange", function() {
//do same stuff 
});
```

This can be further combined into a single event listener

```
$('.myClass').on('DOMSubtreeModified propertychange', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: $(".myClass").bind("DOMSubtreeModified propertychange", function() {
//do stuff
});